# releasing content by role within a D2L topic

Tags: javascript, desire2learn

I'm trying to release content by role within a topic in D2L's LMS. Is this possible using Javascript? Something like, "if {RoleName}=Student, then display this, else display that"...? I realize I can restrict/release content by role on a topic level, but I'm trying to do so within a topic and thus can't use release conditions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can control that functionality directly through the Content tool interface without needing to add in JavaScript. If you don't have access to that in Content, talk to your site administrator.

Comment: I _am_ the site administrator. I don't think this functionality is built-in. As I wrote originally, Release Conditions are certainly applicable on the topic level, but I'm talking about WITHIN the topic, within the source code of the topic itself. Hence, this is why I suspect JS would be necessary. Let me know if I've misunderstood you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout way to do this would be to parse the QueryString to get the OU, then make a Valence request to find out the user role in the course.  It would take a lot of work to get all the pieces connected for what seems like a really simple use case.  This is the strategy I'm using for tools I've made that get embedded right in D2L pages.

If Replacement Strings worked properly then you could use a combination of them and JavaScript.  But since the replacement happens at save time rather than render time in most places, they're really not usable for your scenario.

[Desire2Learn Replace Strings in Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772647/desire2learn-replace-strings-in-content)

Another option would be to create your own custom widget and put it on the course home page.  Since Replacement Strings work properly in widgets, you could read the value of the {rolename} replacement string and store it in a cookie.  Then, in your pages you would read the value of the cookie to create your conditionals.