# Desire2Learn Replace Strings in Content

Tags: desire2learn

I understand there is a function called "replace strings" that allow [information to be substituted](http://mooreaboutd2l.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/another-great-use-for-replace-strings/) in the D2L tools. What strings are available and can I use them in the content tools?

Answer (score 1):

In the Desire2Learn Content tool the replace strings functionality substitutes at *save* time and not *render* time.  This limits the applicability of the the replace strings in content.

The replace strings that are available include:

email

externalemail

firstname

internalemail

lastname

orgdefinedid

orgid

orgname

orgunitcode

orgunitid

orgunitname

orgunitpath

orgunittypeid

rolecode

roleid

rolename

userid

username

Comment: Any plans to change the D2L Content Tool to do the substitution at render time?  Almost all of our replacement string usage would be in content if they worked they way we want them to there.

Comment: No planned/scheduled work for replacement strings at render time that I am aware of.