# Custom replacement strings from third party app

Tags: desire2learn

Is there any ability to populate a learning module's content using data passed from a third party application. For example:

Third party data:

> userid = 12,  username = Sally,  user_q1_answer = Jim,  user_q2_answer
>   = 101

Module Content setup:

> [[username]], since you are in room [[user_q1_answer]], you should
>   contact [[user_q2_answer]] in the event of the fire alarm going off.

Module Content Delivered:

> **Sally**, since you are in room **101**, you should contact **Jim** in the event of the fire alarm going off.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no facility in the LMS exists to do this kind of dynamic substitution at render time. A number of other questions [here have covered this ground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772647/desire2learn-replace-strings-in-content). As of Spring 2013, this kind of functionality is on the development roadmap but there is not yet a committed release vehicle for it.

It *might* be possible to use a client-side browser extension to detect specially formatted strings in page content and make Valence Learning Framework API calls to find values it can replace those strings with. However, this technique would probably only practically be able to replace values that are known about the current *user* and their relationship to the LMS. Through URL and page content examination, it might also be possible to gather knowledge about the user's current browsing context (i.e. what course or course section they're looking at), but we never recommend screen-scraping because you can't depend on meaningful tokens or data appearing reliably going forward (where as you can depend on the Learning Framework APIs to be able to get you information about the current operating user).